# Facebook login flutter app error

Tags: facebook, android-studio, dart, flutter

I have encountered the following FB error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URL is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL
>   you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

Also Facebook OAuth redirect URI, does not accept http local host.

Comment: Please add more information what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed with the full and exact error messages you got (if any).

Comment: See [ask], especially [mcve].

Comment: I have a Facebook Login button in my app, where I give the option to the user to login with facebook, I am pretty sure I have followed the setup correctly by using few tutorials online on what to add into my Manifesto, info.plist and so on, however whenever I try to login with facebook through my app, it gives me this error on a facebook page: Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration: One or more of the given URL is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to review the OAuth settings for your Facebook application

[image: FB settings]

> Also Facebook OAuth redirect URI, does not accept http local host

HTTPS is [required for new Facebook integrations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security). You can get free certificates from Lets Encrypt or use self-signed certs and add them to your mobile device. It's a little more complicated, but it's really for the best :-)